# Unicode decode error in YUI Compressor plugin for Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, yui-compressor

I can't seem to get the [Yui Compressor plugin](https://github.com/leon/YUI-Compressor) for [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) working, and keep getting the error like:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x9e in position 19: ordinal not in range(128)
Writing file /C/Users/Nikola Brežnjak/Desktop/yuicompressor-2.4.7/build/justTesting.js with encoding UTF-8
Running java -jar C:\Users\Nikola Brežnjak\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\YUI Compressor\bin\yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar --charset utf-8 --preserve-semi --line-break 150 -o justTesting.min.js C:\Users\Nikola Brežnjak\Desktop\yuicompressor-2.4.7\build\justTesting.js
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\sublime_plugin.py", line 337, in run_
  File ".\exec.py", line 154, in run
  File ".\exec.py", line 45, in __init__
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x9e in position 19: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I installed the plugin via package manager and I made sure I've put java in my PATH variable and if I run it via the console the YUI Compressor does its job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was with the path in which my Sublime Text is installed - notice the **ž** character in my surname.

So, after a lot of searching I found out the solution **[here](https://github.com/misfo/Shell-Turtlestein/issues/6#issuecomment-4249064)**, and as stated there it seems to be the error within the `exec.py` file, which can be found in your Sublime Packages directory (for example: `C:\Users\Nikola Brežnjak\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Default`). You have to change the **line 45** from:

```
proc_env[k] = os.path.expandvars(v).encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
```

to:

```
proc_env[k] = os.path.expandvars(v.decode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())).encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
```

After this you have to save the file, and the plugin will reload automatically, and then the YUI compressor plugin will work flawlessly.